# Trouble reading text from file

Tags: visual-studio, file, c++17

I have a text source file which contains the following line

```
Hello, "#%First sentence with #"
```

I will need to replace all `#%` to `1%`
The arguments are filename, `#%` as from, `1%` as to

Here is my code,

```
void UpdateSourceFile (std::string sourceFile, const std::string from, const std::string to) 
{
    std::string line;
    int lineNumber = 0, pos = 0;
    int flen = from.length();
    int tlen = to.length();

    std::ifstream source(sourceFile.c_str());

    while (std::getline(source, line)) {
        
        lineNumber++;
        
        while ((pos = line.find(from, pos)) != std::string::npos) {
            line.replace(pos, flen, to);
            pos += tlen;
        }
    }
    source.close();
}
```

In this code, in the first while loop, when the code reads  `std::getline(source, line)`
the line is received as

```
"Hello, \"#%First sentence with #\""
```

In the inner while loop, the code fails to find `#%` even though it's present.

This code works well if the quotation aren't present in the line.

Please suggest modification.

Comment: After you process the very first line, you end up with `pos == npos`. All subsequent `line.find(from, pos)` calls naturally don't find anything. You probably meant to reset `pos` to zero for each new line.

Comment: Resetting `pos` to zero for each line makes my code working perfectly working. Thank you so much @IgorTandetnik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the code to reset `pos` before scanning each line. The logic works perfectly.

```
while (std::getline(source, line)) {
    lineNumber++;
    pos = 0;

    while ((pos = line.find(from, pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        line.replace(pos, flen, to);
        pos += tlen;
    }
}
```